# When to use *is* and *was* in context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can we use *is* as passive voice?

Is/Was are used to describe Truth or something that is repetitive in the present and past respectively.

What would be the correct answer of guide?

The context is that visitor is visiting the Taj-mahal. He asked guide that who built the 
Taj mahal. What should be the answer of guide?

Who built the Tajmahal?

1st Ans: Tajmahal is built by Shah Jahan

or

2nd Ans: Tajmahal was built by Shah Jahan

Explanation

1st Ans : Answer is in present passive voice or in Active voice?.  It gives *idea of truth* that it is built by Shah Jahan. But is also gives idea that every time it is built by Shah Jahan. Like in another example "Car is cleaned by John" gives idea that every day car is cleaned by John.

2nd Ans: Answer is in simple past passive voice. It gives idea in the past i.e. century ago it was built by shah Jahan.  But it also gives idea of repetitive action of building Taj Mahal in the past. Like 
“This trust was run by Mother Theresa.” It Gives idea that when Mother Theresa was alive this trust was run by her.

Some more examples:

This movie is brought to you by.....?

This show is presented for you by....?

Answer (score 1):

**Is** is present tense, *always*.

You could never say *The Taj Mahal is built by Shah Jahan* because this occurred many years ago and is not currently occurring.

Also, even if the Taj Mahal was currently under construction, the correct phrasing would be *The Taj Mahal is **being** built by Shah Jahan.* Though this is problematic because it's implying that Shah Jahan himself is physically doing the actual labor of building the Taj Mahal.

The correct phrase of the two is *The Taj Mahal was built by Shah Jahan*... and even this has some of the false implication but it's generally understood that what is actually meant is *The Taj Mahal was built [at the direction of] Shah Jahan*.

I'm not sure where you're getting:

> But it also gives idea of repetitive action of building Taj Mahal in the past.

There is only one Taj Mahal... it was built only once. There is no repetition of action here.

---

In your other examples:

> **The** car is cleaned by John.

This is ok but not commonly used. There is **no** implication that he does so every day, though. All it means is that, if and when the car gets cleaned, (each month/year/week) John is the one who does it. The much more common option is *John cleans the car.*

> This trust was run by Mother Theresa.

This is fine.

> This movie is brought to you by.....?
>
> This show is presented for you by....?

These are common phrases used to lead into ads on TV channels. They don't necessarily have a repetitive feel, particularly as shows aren't always sponsored by the same company for every episode or even every airing of the episode.

Comment: Thanks Catija.  But i read that simple present tense may use to express truth. And in my sentence taj mahal is built by shah jahan is truth

Comment: [*while you can use the present tense and say "Othello **is** by Shakespeare," when using the verbs **penned, written, composed,** etc., you have to use past tense. The difference, I guess, is that while the play was written in the past, it **is now and always will be** by Shakespeare.*](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2749990)